# Why is the Hekesh not on Rabbi Yishmael's list?

Tags: midrash, lomdus

Rabbi Yishmael has a list of 13 ways the Torah's expounded. Why is the Hekesh not included?

Comment: Can you [edit] to define what exactly you mean by "Hekesh" and perhaps provide an example? Are there any of the 13 that are similar but you don't think could include it? If so, why not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This excellent question is asked in **Sefer Kritut** of [**Rabbi Shimshon MiKinon**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samson_of_Chinon), the main book of Klale Hashas. I will copy a couple of statements in English.

First you can see the answer in "ot"  ["יג"](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=20728&st=&pgnum=82)  but you need first to read "ot"  ["יב"](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=20728&st=&pgnum=81&hilite=) .

I think that for you this is sufficient but we need give an English answer. A rough translation of this passage:

> In Gemara, Rabbi Akiva and Rabanan have different opinions about the question: "Hekesh is the strongest or Gzera Shava is the strongest?".
>
> ... Anyway, we can say that for Rabbi Yishmael Hekehs is the strongest. So all is explained: he doesn't counted the Hekesh because Hekesh is as if the thing is written explicitely {and is not a Drasha}