# Hekesh vs Gezeira Shava

Tags: maseches-gitin, gezeira-shava

[Gittin 41b](https://www.sefaria.org/Gittin.41b.5?lang=bi&lang2=en) discusses whether a Gezeira Shava or Hekesh "is stronger" (prevails). The arguments back and forth are not relevant to my question.

The `״לָהּ״–״לָהּ״` Gezeira Shava is **not** attacked from the POV that one of the words ***is*** necessary: the ***lishma*** *get* requirement is derived from it.

**Why is this deficiency of the Gezeira Shava never mentioned (neither here nor on [39b](https://www.sefaria.org/Gittin.39b.2?lang=bi&lang2=en))?**

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/73228/9215

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Penei Yehoshua on 41b explains that although the two times the word ״לה״ is written regarding divorce is not superfluous - one is to teach that it must be written for her sake, and one is to teach that you can’t write a divorce for the sake of two women - nevertheless it is enough that at least by redeeming a slave it is written for the Gezairah Shavah, being that if it would be coming to teach us one of the two rules that are mentioned above regarding divorce, it should have indicated which rule it comes to teach, therefore, because it is unclear, and we wouldn’t be able to learn anything out of it, it must be coming to teach us this Gezairah Shavah